# Pegar valores de inputs em html para objeto em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5

Queria saber como faço para pegar as informações dos dados inseridos no input html para criar um objeto pelo meu modelo MVC e salvar no banco de dados. Obs: já tenho todas as classes de modelo, as classes de interface, só preciso montar os objetos com os dados para fazer o post dos dados.

![Segue imagem de como está o html]https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQLmO.jpg

Um pedaço do HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="Email" class="control-label">Email</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
     <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Boa noite... 
Estou entendendo que voce está trabalhando com MVC... Então seria mais ou menos assim
o form aciona a Controller que deve executar o seguinte código:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = Email)] Project project, HttpPostedFileBase filetransfer)
    {
            context.Project.Add(project);
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Espero ter ajudado!